# How to add dict values to mongodb documents with fields equals dict keys?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the collection of documents in mongodb like this:

```
{
  {"name": "John"},
  {"name": "Mike"},
  {"name": "Andrew"}
}
```

Also I have a python dict:

```
{
"John": [1, 3, 3, 7],
"Mike": [9, 0, 9],
"Andrew": [7]
}
```

I want to add dict value for every document which "name" matching with dict key.
I think that I should using something like db.collection.aggregate and group documents by name, but I don't know how to match dict values with grouping results.

The results should be:

```
{
  {"name": "John", "arr": [1, 3, 3, 7]},
  {"name": "Mike", "arr": [9, 0, 9]},
  {"name": "Andrew" "arr": [7]}
}
```

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_ = [
  {"name": "John"},
  {"name": "Mike"},
  {"name": "Andrew"}
]

arr_2 = {
    "John": [1, 3, 3, 7],
    "Mike": [9, 0, 9],
    "Andrew": [7]
}

for key, item in enumerate(arr_):
    arr_[key]["arr"] = arr_2[item["name"]]
```

output :

```
[
     {'name': 'John', 'arr': [1, 3, 3, 7]}, 
     {'name': 'Mike', 'arr': [9, 0, 9]}, 
     {'name': 'Andrew', 'arr': [7]}
]
```

Comment: Yea, I know how to do it in python, the question is how it make in mongo database by query.

Comment: If your python dict is not stored somewhere in the database. It is not possible to do an aggregate and append data that are not stored in mongodb